# How can I print out string records stored in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am working on a project using C. I store several records in a two-dimensional array of strings, where one string is the record name and the other string is the actual value. For example:

```
myArray[0][0] = "filename1";
myArray[0][1] = "somefile.txt";
myArray[1][0] = "filename2";
myArray[1][1] = "anotherfile.txt";
// and so on ...
```

I know how to store the values in the array, but I'm not sure how to print them out. Can you please help me figure it out?

Comment: See if you can make the question a bit clearer - this is disjointed English and hard to understand.

Comment: Please learn a bit of English first, asking for a reply ASAP is not really appropriate nor nice. Please clarify your question first.

Comment: Karthikeyan: I re-wrote your question according to what I think you meant to say. Please look it over and make sure that it is correct.

Answer (score 6):

try if you are working with a 2d array chars (ie 1d array of strings)

```
your_2d_array[0] = "file_name_1" /* and so on ... */


for( i = 0 ; i < num_of_file_names ; i++ )
{
    printf("%s\n", your_2d_array[i]);
}
```

If you are working with a 2d array of strings (ie 3d array of chars) as the edit seems to indicated then simply do the following

```
for( i = 0; i < num_of_file_names ; i++ )
{
    printf("%s : %s \n", your_2d_array[i][0], your_2d_array[i][1] );
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a 1d array for a start, but I'm not going to mod you down since I didn't understand the question.

Comment: A 2d array of characters is a 1d array of c-strings, so I think that would work.

Comment: @Pax I assumed the questioner meant a 2d array of chars, from the initial version of the question it wasn't clear what was meant by a 2d array. I've added an alternative answer based on the edit by eJames

Comment: No probs, made minor fix to array index, then +1, good answer.

Comment: @hhafez: I didn't even consider the fact that a 1D array of char * could be interpreted as a 2D array of type char. +1 from me, too.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the following:

```
int recordIndex;
for (recordIndex = 0; recordIndex < num_records; recordIndex++)
{
    printf("%s: %s\n", myArray[recordIndex][0], myArray[recordIndex][1]);
}
```

Which will output as follows:

```
filename1: somefile.txt
filename2: anotherfile.txt
...
```